# On delete cascade error - How can I solve it with trigger?

Tags: sql, sql-server

My query to create some tables in SQL Server 2012 are as following:

```
create table Poll_Question_Table (
    PollQuestionId int primary key,
    PollQuestionTex varchar(max),
    PollStatus int ,
    PollStartDate date,
    PollEndDate date,
    PollCatagoryId int foreign key references Poll_Catagory_Table on update cascade on delete cascade  
)

create table Poll_Catagory_Table(
    PollCatagoryId int primary key,
    PollCatagoryName varchar(100),
    PollCatagoryDescription varchar(max)
)

create table Poll_Answer_Table(
    PollAnswerId int primary key,
    PollAnswerText varchar(max),
    PollQuestionId int foreign key references Poll_Question_Table on update cascade on delete cascade
)

create table Poll_Vote_Table (
    PollVoteId int primary key,
    PollQuestionId int foreign key references Poll_Question_Table on update cascade on delete cascade ,
    PollAnswerId int foreign key references Poll_Answer_Table on update cascade on delete cascade,
    PollCount int 
)
```

and the error is

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK__Poll_Vote__PollA__5A3A55A2' on
>   table 'Poll_Vote_Table' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths.
>   Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other
>   FOREIGN KEY constraints.
>   how can i solve this one

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. Add the other two table definitions as well.

Comment: Why do You want to make delete from main table after You deleted record in lower table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Their is many ways to solve your problem. I will present only two solutions:

1- The simpliest one: Changing your table Poll_Vote_Table into 2 table one for Questions, one for Answers.

2- Use trigger instead of delete/update. It's actually what you want, but please consider solution 1. Now the code to use trigger ([for reference](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2733/solving-the-sql-server-multiple-cascade-path-issue-with-a-trigger/)):

(I'll just illustrate for the Question part. For Answer, it's the same.)

First you will have to recreate your FK as follow (after delete) :

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Poll_Vote_Table]  WITH CHECK 
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Vote_Question] FOREIGN KEY([PollQuestionId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Poll_Question_Table] ([PollQuestionId])
```

Then you will need to create the triggers :

```
CREATE TRIGGER [DELETE_Question_Vote]
   ON dbo.[Poll_Question_Table]
   INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS 
BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;
 DELETE FROM [Poll_Vote_Table] WHERE PollQuestionId IN (SELECT PollQuestionId FROM DELETED)
 DELETE FROM [Poll_Question_Table] WHERE PollQuestionId IN (SELECT PollQuestionId FROM DELETED)
END
GO
```

The update part is usually of no use, so I won't write about it but it's basicly the same as DELETE.

Comment: Just for information you can also go for an after DELETE using `CREATE TRIGGER [DELETE_Question_Vote]
   ON dbo.[Poll_Question_Table]
   FOR DELETE
AS ` and you wouldn't need FK anymore. It could create a sort of "safe code".